# Tithing and excommunication question (LDS)

Tags: lds, tithe, excommunication

Member of LDS Church asking:

Will the LDS hierarchy excommunicate me if I do not pay them the required 10% of the difference between my home purchase price and my home sale price? Anyone know about that? It is a bit more than just a tithing question because I had to pay $44.000 of home value in a divorce settlement, and I don't know if the LDS Church will take that into consideration.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Your question *may* be answerable here, since it is about LDS church policy. However, since this is a personal and somewhat complex situation, I would recommend that you talk to a person who is in a position within the LDS church to answer it definitively. For more on what this site is all about, please see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Comment: This question is perhaps better suited to be asked of your local church leader (bishop or branch president).

Comment: I do not want to ask him Joshua, that's why I am asking here

Comment: Why don't you pray about it? The commandment is 10% of your increase. Did you receive an increase?

Comment: I think the $44K would count as an increase for whomever received it, and not you, but like Matt said, it's between you and the Lord. What feels like an honest tithe to you?

Comment: I've never heard of anyone being excommunicated for not paying tithing. Usually only serious moral issues (such as murder or physical/sexual abuse) or repeated public opposition to the church would lead to excommunication. Also, even if not paying tithing were grounds for excommunication, the church isn't in the business of tracking members' finances, especially to an extent that they could tell you that you owed a certain amount.

Comment: Related question: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/25954/16847

Comment: Also related: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/44602/can-a-mormon-reach-salvation-if-they-do-not-pay-tithes

Answer (score 4):

> "Those who pay tithing do not do so under the duress of legal compulsion. No one is disfellowshipped or excommunicated because he fails to pay."
>
> —Gorden B. Hinkley, "[My Testimony](https://www.lds.org/general-conference/1993/10/my-testimony?lang=eng)", General Conference, October 1993.

Declaring yourself a [full tithe payer](https://www.lds.org/ensign/2010/08/being-worthy-to-enter-the-temple?lang=eng) is one of the qualifications for holding a recommend to enter the temple.

Tithing is defined by the following:

> In 1838 the Lord reiterated this commandment through the Prophet Joseph Smith:
>
> “My people … shall pay one-tenth of all their interest annually; and this shall be a standing law unto them forever” ([Doctrine and Covenants 119:3–4](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/119.3-4?lang=eng#2)). Interest is understood to mean income.
>
> —[*Tithing and Fast Offerings*](https://www.lds.org/manual/tithing-and-fast-offerings/what-is-tithing?lang=eng)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not gonna answer your question as-is because it's personal, but in general:

Tithing is between the individual and the Lord. Whatever the member honestly considers to be 10% of their increase or income is according to their conscience. At the end of every year, members are asked to declare their tithing payments to their bishop (and settle any discrepancies in the books, if present). One declares himself/herself being either a full tithe payer, partial tithe payer, or not a tithe payer.

Being a full tithe payer is [one of the qualifications](https://www.lds.org/ensign/2010/08/being-worthy-to-enter-the-temple?lang=eng) for holding a recommend to enter the temple.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody will be excommunicated for not paying tithing. And nobody will dictate to you exactly what constitutes your 10%. If you don't feel like you can honestly answer that you are a full tithe payer, you will not be able to get a Temple recommend, but will otherwise be like any other member. No one but the Bishop will even know.